# how to send spinner value from activity to fragment in android studio

Tags: java, android, sql

I have dynamic spinner i get value of spinner from database  i want that after selecting that value send this spinner value into fragment textview.
i know there is alot of helping question here i tried one by one all of them but didnt got my solution. i am so worried about my code. please help me friends

i have tried my best but in vain.
my code is here
**XML OF Activity**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ui.AirportSelection">
  <Spinner
                        android:id="@+id/sp_flight"
                        android:layout_width="270dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:clickable="true"
                        android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"

                       />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/date"
                        android:layout_width="270dp"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                        android:ems="10"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="14dp"

                        android:layout_below="@+id/sp_flight"


                        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />
 <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_submit"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonlogin"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="Submit"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Activity**

```
public class AirportSelection extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Spinner customSpinner;
    TextView date;
    NetworkManager networkManager = new NetworkManager();
    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager();
    Button reg_button;
    List<String> skinNamesList = new ArrayList<>();
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Connection conn;
    boolean isSucess = false;
    String sp_flight;
    String Flightdate;
    private FragmentManager mFragmentManager;
    private FragmentTransaction mFragmentTransaction;
    private static FragmentManager fragmentManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_airport_selection);
        customSpinner = findViewById(R.id.sp_flight);
        reg_button = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit);
        fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
       FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        final FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
       final cleaning myFragment = new cleaning();
       String date_n = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).format(new Date());
//get hold of textview.
        date  = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
//set it as current date.
        date.setText(date_n);
        Flightdate = date.getText().toString().trim();

        GetAllSkinTone skinTone = new GetAllSkinTone();
        skinTone.execute();
        reg_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                CreateUserAccount createUserAccount = new CreateUserAccount();
                createUserAccount.execute();
                Intent intent = new Intent(AirportSelection.this, UserDashboardActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                senddata();
             


            }
        });





    }
    private class CreateUserAccount extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AirportSelection.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Saving value please wait!");
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
               /* Flightdate = getDateTime();*/

                ConnectionHelper con = new ConnectionHelper();
                conn = con.connectionclasss(Const.DBUserNameStr, Const.DBPasswordStr, Const.db, Const.ip);
                String queryStmt = "Insert into FlightSelection " +
                        " (FlightNo, FlightDate) values "
                        + "('"
                        + sp_flight
                        + "','"
                        + Flightdate
                        + "')";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                isSucess = stmt.execute(queryStmt);
                isSucess = true;
                conn.close();
                // return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isSucess = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (isSucess) {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                }


            } else {
                if (progressDialog.isShowing()) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    sharedPrefManager.loginPreference(AirportSelection.this, 0);
                    Toast.makeText(AirportSelection.this, "Account not created", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }

    class GetAllSkinTone extends AsyncTask<List<Map<String, String>>, Void, List<Map<String, String>>> {
        Map<String, String> datanum;
        ProgressDialog progressDialog;
        List<Map<String, String>> data;
        Connection connect;
        String ConnectionResult = "";
        Boolean isSuccess = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //loading until data load
            progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(AirportSelection.this);
            progressDialog.setTitle("Loading please wait!");
            progressDialog.show();
            super.onPreExecute();
        }

        @SuppressLint("WrongThread")
        @Override
        protected List<Map<String, String>> doInBackground(List<Map<String, String>>... lists) {
            data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();
            try {
                ConnectionHelper conStr = new ConnectionHelper();
                connect = conStr.connectionclasss(Const.DBUserNameStr, Const.DBPasswordStr, Const.db, Const.ip);        // Connect to database
                if (connect == null) {
                    ConnectionResult = "Check Your Internet Access!";
                } else {
                    // Change below query according to your own database.
                    // String query = "select * from countries";
                    //get all category from Category TABLE
                    Statement stmt = connect.createStatement();
                    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT FlightNumber FROM flight");
                    while (rs.next()) {
                        datanum = new HashMap<>();

                        datanum.put("SkinColors", rs.getString("FlightNumber"));

                        skinNamesList.add(rs.getString("FlightNumber"));
//                        customSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                        // categoryList.add(new Category(rs.getInt("CategoryId"), rs.getString("CategoryName"), "http://192.168.10.11/" + rs.getString("CatImage")));
                        data.add(datanum);
                    }
                    ConnectionResult = " successful";
                    isSuccess = true;
                    connect.close();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                isSuccess = false;
                ConnectionResult = ex.getMessage();
            }

            return data;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Map<String, String>> maps) {
            super.onPostExecute(maps);
            if (isSuccess) {
                skinNamesList.add(0, "Select Flight No");
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(AirportSelection.this, R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item, skinNamesList);
                customSpinner.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
                customSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                        sp_flight = skinNamesList.get(position);



                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                    }
                });
            } else {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(AirportSelection.this, "No Record found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    }

    private String getDateTime() {
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d/yyyy");
        java.util.Date date = new Date();
        return dateFormat.format(date);
    }

    private void senddata(){


     /* Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        //bundle.putString("NAME_KEY", customSpinner.getText().toString());

      bundle.putInt("NAME_KEY", Integer.valueOf(sp_flight.getSelectedItem().toString()));
        cleaning myfragment = new cleaning();
        myfragment.setArguments(bundle);
        sp_flight.setSelection(0);
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,myfragment).commit();*/

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(AirportSelection.this, cleaning.class);
        intent.putExtra("name", sp_flight);

        startActivity(intent);



    }
}
```

**XML OF Fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".fragment.cleaning"
    android:id="@+id/cleaning"
    >

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/bgheader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"

        android:elevation="5dp"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:elevation="10dp"
        android:textColor="@color/navyblue"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:text="ON-Time Cleaning Tracker"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        />
    <ScrollView
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/scrollview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/bgheader"
        >
        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center"
            >
            <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
                android:id="@+id/cardview"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="20dp"
                app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
                app:cardElevation="2dp"
                >
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    >
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tventer"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"

                            android:ems="10"
                            android:text="Start Time"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"

                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtentertime"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"


                            android:ems="10"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"


                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvstart"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"

                            android:ems="10"
                            android:text="Start Time"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"

                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtstarttime"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"


                            android:ems="10"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"


                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvend"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"

                            android:ems="10"
                            android:text="End Time"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"

                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtendtime"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"


                            android:ems="10"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"


                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvexit"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"

                            android:ems="10"
                            android:text="End Time"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"

                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />



                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtexittime"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"


                            android:ems="10"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"


                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/tvdiff"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:text="Time Taken"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"

                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp" />

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/txtdifference"
                            android:layout_width="0dp"
                            android:layout_height="50dp"
                            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
                            android:layout_marginStart="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:textColor="@color/blue"
                            android:ems="10"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"

                            android:textColorHint="@color/blue"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
                            android:layout_marginRight="10dp" />
                    </LinearLayout>




                </LinearLayout>

            </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/cardview"

                android:elevation="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

                >
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="60dp"
                    android:elevation="10dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonlogin"
                    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
                    android:text="Start"
                    android:textStyle="bold"
                    android:textAllCaps="false"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    android:textSize="22dp" />

            </RelativeLayout>
        </RelativeLayout>
    </ScrollView>




</RelativeLayout>
```

**Fragment**

```
public class cleaning extends Fragment {
    TextView tvstarttime;
    Button btn_start;
    Button btn_end;
    TextView tvend;
    TextView tventer;
    TextView tvexit;
    TextView diffence;
    boolean isStarted = false;
    String starttime, endtime, timedifference, date;
    ProgressDialog progressDialog;
    Connection conn;
    boolean isSucess = false;
    NetworkManager networkManager = new NetworkManager();
    SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager();
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_cleaning, container, false);
        tvstarttime = view.findViewById(R.id.txtstarttime);
        btn_start = view.findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        tvend = view.findViewById(R.id.txtendtime);
        tventer = view.findViewById(R.id.txtentertime);
        tvexit= view.findViewById(R.id.txtexittime);
        diffence=view.findViewById(R.id.txtdifference);
        //Bundle bundle = getArguments();
       // String selectedVAlue = bundle.getString("sp_flight");
       // tvexit.setText(selectedVAlue);
        /*FlightSelection activity= (FlightSelection) getActivity();
        Intent f = activity.getIntent();
        String spinnerValue = f.getStringExtra("sp_flight");
        tvexit.setText(spinnerValue);*/




        Bundle extras = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extras != null) {
            String getUsername = extras.getString("name");
            tvexit.setText(getUsername);
        }

        btn_start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                if (isStarted){
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                    String time = format.format(calendar.getTime());
                    tvend.setText(time);
                    endtime = tvend.getText().toString().trim();
                    try {
                        Date date1 = format.parse(tvend.getText().toString());
                        Date date2 = format.parse(tvstarttime.getText().toString());
                        long mills = date1.getTime() - date2.getTime();
                        Log.v("Data1", ""+date1.getTime());
                        Log.v("Data2", ""+date2.getTime());
                        int hours = (int) (mills/(1000 * 60 * 60));
                        int mins = (int) (mills % (1000*60*60));
                        String diff = hours + ":" + mins;
                        diffence.setText(diff);
                        timedifference = diffence.getText().toString().trim();
                        uploadCleaningTable uploadtable = new uploadCleaningTable();
                        uploadtable.execute();
                    }
                    catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    btn_start.setText("START");
                }else {
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss aa");
                    String time1 = format.format(calendar.getTime());
                    tvstarttime.setText(time1);
                    starttime = tvstarttime.getText().toString().trim();
                    btn_start.setText("STOP");
                }
                isStarted = !isStarted;
            }
        });
return view;
    }
    private class uploadCleaningTable extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            try {
                ConnectionHelper con = new ConnectionHelper();
                conn = con.connectionclasss(Const.DBUserNameStr, Const.DBPasswordStr, Const.db, Const.ip);
                String queryStmt = "Insert into CleaningTable" +
                        " (StartTime, StopTime, TimeTaken) values "
                        + "('"
                        + starttime
                        + "','"
                        + endtime
                        + "','"
                        + timedifference
                        + "')";
                Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
                isSucess = stmt.execute(queryStmt);
                isSucess = true;
                conn.close();
                // return data;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                isSucess = false;
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            if (isSucess) {
               Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "time added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "time not added", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post your other code?

Comment: I have posted my both activity and fragment code above. please help me. i have to move spinner value with is saved on sp_flight string variable and show it into fragment textview

Comment: how are you showing your fragment? I mean in which activity?

Comment: @RudraRokaya i am navigation drawer and with in that drawer i am using different fragment.